# How to detect the ordered position of a class element

Tags: javascript

Detecting the name of a class is straightforward.

`event.target.className`

However detecting if a given element is the 3rd, 5th or 11th that uses a particular class is tough, at least for me.  I used the console (F12) to find a property I could use but no luck.

In the following simplified example what property or other feature can determine if the user clicked `("box-a")[0]` `("box-a")[1]` `("box-a")[2]` or `("box-a")[3]`?  I know that I can use individual IDs for each element but I'd rather keep this simple if it is technically possible.

```js
var count;
 
for (count = 0; count < 4; count++) {
  document.getElementsByClassName("box-a")[count].addEventListener("click", checker);
}

function checker() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("box-b")[0].innerHTML = event.target.className;
}

// event.target.className targets the classes name, but what property targets the [0], [1], [2] or [3]?
```

```css
.box-a {
  background-color: green;
  border: 0.6rem solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 4rem;
}

.box-b {
  display: block;
  background-color: blue;
  border: .25rem solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 4rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-a">Box 1</div>
<div class="box-a">Box 2</div>
<div class="box-a">Box 3</div>
<div class="box-a">Box 4</div>
<div class="box-b"></div>
```

Comment: What are you planning to do with the index once you get it?

Answer (score 0):

When looping over the elements, add an event listener to each box that passes the index of the clicked box to your `checker` function.

```js
function checker(index) {
    // Do whatever you want with the index here
    console.log(index)
}

// Add the same event listener to each element, but passing the index of
// the element to the checker function
[].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('box-a'))
    .forEach(function(element, index) {
        element.addEventListener('click', function() { checker(index) })
    })
```

```html
<div class="box-a">Box 1</div>
<div class="box-a">Box 2</div>
<div class="box-a">Box 3</div>
<div class="box-a">Box 4</div>
<div class="box-a">Box 5</div>
```

Comment: The problem with this answer is that the index will be hardcoded, let's say you remove the third element, the "Box 4" will still have index 3.

Comment: @Gerardo OK, you didn't mention that. Workaround: When boxes are added/removed, detach all the event listeners, and re-add?

Comment: I didn't mention that because I'm not the one who asked the question. I just thought that he probably want to add/remove the elements and this answer will only work at first, before an element is added or removed. About attaching/detaching the listeners will work for sure but it's not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

This may be not the best solution but it works.

```
// Click on any div element and see the output

document.querySelectorAll('.box-a').forEach((e) => { // Add the event listener to all the elements with class .box-a
  e.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    var element = event.target;
    var index = Array.from(element 
      .parentNode // Get the parent node of the clicked element
      .querySelectorAll('.' + element.className)) // Select all the elements inside the parent node (siblings) with the same class name of the clicked element
      .indexOf(element) + 1; // Look for the index of the clicked element, + 1 
    console.log(index);
  });
});
```

Here's a working bin:

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/tiwahilulu/1/edit?js,console,output)